# Preview uploaded document in expo react native

Tags: typescript, react-native, expo

i have a problem with viewing the uploaded file. any one have idea?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PrHau.png)

see picture please, i use react native with expo and i code a button that enable to upload files(doc,pdf)
but I can not find a way or method to show the files and its extensions.

```
state = {
    };
DocPick = async () => {
        let DocPrint = await DocumentPicker.getDocumentAsync({});
          alert("sucess");
// here after the alert comes the file name + type + preview
      console.log(DocPrint);
      
    }

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Button color='#8098db'
          title=" CHOOSE FILE " 
          onPress={this.DocPick} />
           <KeyboardAvoidingView behavior="padding" enabled>
        <WebView source={{ uri: 'https://dev.pjsc.bothrs.com' }} />
      </KeyboardAvoidingView>
    

      </View>
    );
  }}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66251590/preview-a-remote-url-pdf-doc-img-file/66253854 this might help.

Comment: does it work for expo and typescript? i got error "Cannot read property 'RNFSFileTypeRegular' of undefined"